# Mobile app: searching tags feature request

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

Something I really don't like about the android app is that you, when you are searching questions on a specific tag, don't have a simple tag search system like, for example Stack Overflow on a pc.

tags on pc:

> [image]
>
> ---

or

---

> [image]
>
> ---

---

mobile app:

> [image]

there are no tag buttons at all!

So you always have to manually type in for example '[c#]'

I think this is pretty annoying. Can Stack Exchange please add these tag-buttons in the mobile app?

Just favorite tags would also be great!